# Communicating with a program using Perl Expect

Tags: perl, ipc, pipe, expect

Im trying to use Expect to talk to a long running interactive process.  I am using cat -un to simulate the process.  My code is as follows:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl 

    use strict; 
    use warnings; 
    use Expect; 

    my $timeout = 4000; 

    my $exp = Expect->spawn("cat -un"); 

    my $text = <STDIN>; 
    $exp->send($text); 

    $text = <STDIN>; 
    $exp->send($text); 

    $exp->expect(undef); # Forever until EOF 
    $exp->expect($timeout); # For a few seconds 
    $exp->expect(0); 

    $text = <STDIN>; 
    $exp->send($text); 

    $exp->expect(undef); # Forever until EOF 
    $exp->expect($timeout); # For a few seconds 
    $exp->expect(0);
```

I press the first string + enter and get no output (obviously).  I enter the second string and press enter and stdout from cat -un dumps to the screen.  My third string does not yield any output, yet I would like it to dump stdout to the screen as well.

My goal is to communicate with an interactive process that puts text on the screen (asking the user to select from a menu), then have the user enter a response and send it to the process (which generates more output and more menus).

Expect seems to be the easiest way to do this.  Please assit me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully grok exactly what you're trying to do but I did come up with this example which spawns `"cat -un"` and then waits for input via `<STDIN>`. Each time it receives input it sends that input to `"cat -n"` and then comes back and waits for more input.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 

use strict; 
use warnings; 
use Expect; 

my $timeout = 5; 

my $exp = Expect->spawn("cat -un"); 

#$exp->debug(3);
$exp->debug(0);

my $text;
my $idx = 1;
while (1) {
    $text = <STDIN>; 
    $exp->send($text); 
    $exp->expect(1);

    print "$idx. sent text -> $text";
    $idx++;
}
```

Running this sript produces this output:

```
% ./myexpect.pl 
s1                          <---- my input
s1
     1  s1
1. sent text -> s1
s2                          <---- my input
s2
     2  s2
2. sent text -> s2
s3                          <---- my input
s3
     3  s3
3. sent text -> s3
s4                          <---- my input
s4
     4  s4
4. sent text -> s4
Ctrl-C                      <---- my input
%
```

If you provide more info as a comment or to the question I can try and  further address your question.